# How does a stack work in a Linked Structure?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, nodes

I understand most of the following code but I am just unclear about how pop method works. I don't understand why when top.getNext() is called it returns the previous node. Same thing up top with the push method. Why is temp.setNext(top) being called and then top is being assigned to temp?

```
public class Stack {

private Node top;

public Stack()
{
    top = null;
}

public void push(int v)
{
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.setValue(v);
    temp.setNext(top);
    top = temp;
}

public int peek()
{
    return top.getValue();
}

public int pop()
{
    int temp = top.getValue();
    top = top.getNext();
    return temp;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return(top == null);
}

public void makeEmpty()
{
    top = null;
}

}

public class Node {

private int value;
private Node next;

public void setValue(int v)
{
    value = v;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setNext(Node n)
{
    next = n;
}

public Node getNext()
{
    return next;
}

}
```

The set next code is what is really confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Stack data structure is working as **LIFO** (last in first out).

Keeping that in mind, the code above is structured in a way that each added node will point the node at the top of the stack. And top will be assigned to reference to this newly added node. This is provided using `setNext ()` method. With the same logic, when a node is popped; its next node, the one added just before it, will be the new top node.

For example, consider that stack is empty. When first node is added, top will reference to this node. When the second node is added, it should be the new top according to LIFO. So when it gets added to the stack, its next node will point to the current top node, the first one. After that top will reference to this new node. Here setting next node to previously added node helps us to find new top node if we pop this newly added node.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to push the values 1,2,3,4 onto the Stack:

> push(1): Stack = {1} | Top is 1
>
> push(2): Stack = {2 => 1} | Top is 2
>
> push(3): Stack = {3 => 2 => 1} | Top is 3
>
> push(4): Stack = {4 => 3 => 2 => 1} | Top is 4

In order to get his behavior when a node is added, you must construct a new node, in this case temp with the value set to the value being added. Now since this node will be the new top, the node that it points to should be the current top of the the stack. Hence the **setNext(top);**. Now to make the new node be the top of the stack, you must set it accordingly via **top = temp;**.

Now if we pop a value from the stack above:

> pop(): returned value = 4 | Stack = {3 => 2 => 1} | Top is 3

In order to get this behavior we get the value of the current top of the stack,so **int temp = top.getValue();**. Now we don't want this node to be top anymore, we want the new top to be the node the current top is pointing to, so **top = top.getNext();**. All that's left is to return the value we stored in temp and we have have properly popped the stack.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, let's review how a stack works conceptually. Let me give an example.

Let's say you are washing dishes. In this example we can only wash 1 dish at a time. The first time you clean a dish you put it flat on the counter. The next dish you clean goes on top of that. Each time you clean a dish, you put 
it top of the existing stack of dishes.  The last dish you cleaned is always on the top of the stack and successively older dishes being successively further down the stack. The bottom dish is the one that was cleaned first.

Now if someone comes along and needs a clean dish, they will not try to pull the bottom dish from the stack. They will simply take the top dish of the stack. In other words, they will do a pop operation.

Let's take another example. Say we push a bird, fish, dog and cat into a stack in that order. It would look like this

```
Stack after bird, fish, dog pushed
----------------------------------
top:    dog
        fish
bottom: bird

Stack after cat pushed
----------------------
top:    cat
        dog
        fish
bottom: bird        

Stack after a pop operation
---------------------------
top:    dog
        fish
bottom: bird
```

When we pop cat from the top of the stack, dog becomes the new top. We know this because we can see the entire stack. However, the code is not able to see the entire stack. So the code does something clever.

When a new animal is pushed onto the stack, the old top is stored with that animal that was just added. In other words cat remembers that dog used to be the top. Why? So that if we pop cat, the top is restored to what it used to be.

That is what the top.getNext() is returning - the old top after a pop to which top is assigned. What the top used to be has become the current top. We now know that dog is the top of the stack.

What does this remembering so that top.getNext() will return the old top? That is accomplished by the temp.setNext(top) that happens when a push is performed. When cat is added, before top is updated to be cat, the old top is saved with cat.